# Retrieving HTTP header values

Tags: coldfusion, http-headers, cgi

How can one retrieve an HTTP header value such as `REFERER` as opposed to using the `CGI` scope?

For example, CGI can be used as such:

```
#CGI.HTTP_REFERER#
```

However, can a header value be retrieved in the same manner without having to use the `<cfhttpparam>` parameter?

```
#HTTP_HEADER.REFERER#
```

Comment: @Ageax My code was using it before, however I've configured the site to work in a development environment with custom ports and no domain name (e.g., localhost:1000) and it seems that this affected the CGI scope in some manner as my `CGI.HTTP_REFERER` is always `[empty string]`. I don't know what the underlying issue is, but based on these results I've decided to switch to using the HTTP HEADER's referer value. I understand it's spoofable, but it's a non-critical feature so the risk is worth the ease of implementation.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.  Was just reading about there being some differences in CGI here http://stephenwithington.com/blog/index.cfm/2008/8/26/CGI-Variables-and-Their-Respective-ColdFusionJava-Servlet-Alternative-Methods . I didn't realize CGI values might be different..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
<cfdump var="#GetHttpRequestData()#" label="GetHttpResponseData() Values"/>
```

Source: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1425-getting-header-values-from-a-coldfusion-request.htm

### Update

To expand on this a little more, the exact line of code would be:

```
#getPageContext().getRequest().getHeader("Referer")#
```

Comment: Just know that `REFERER` is a highly unreliable header. It an often be blank when people expect it to be populated.